# JAVA8: Find the file with the newest date in its filename

Tags: java, collections, java-8

I have few files in an FTP folder with names like:

> mainimport_31052017.csv
>   mainimport_21052017.csv
>   mainimport_15052017.csv

And I have a pattern string:

> String pattern = "mainimport_ddmmyyy";

Now I am supposed to download the file with the latest date in its title. I am supposed to do it with Java 8 goodies.

I have a solution, but this is not pretty enough, I am doing it in 2 statements:

1) I first get the newest date:

```
Date newestDate = Collections.max(ftpFiles.stream().filter(fileName -> StringUtils.startsWith(fileName.getName(), prefix)).map(fileName -> {
    String fileNameSuffix = fileName.getName().split("_")[1];
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = dateFormat.parse(fileNameSuffix);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return date;
}).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

2) I then get the filename with the latest date:

```
Optional<FTPFile> file = ftpFiles.stream().filter(fileName->{
    String fileNameSuffix = fileName.getName().split("_")[1];
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = dateFormat.parse(fileNameSuffix);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return StringUtils.startsWith(fileName.getName(), prefix) && date.equals(newestDate);

}).findFirst();
```

I am trying to do this both in a single statement, if it is possible.

Comment: Working code that is simply "not pretty enough" does not belong on Stack Overflow. You should post on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: If you're supposed to use Java 8 "goodies", then you **shouldn't** be using the `Date` or `Calendar` classes, but the `java.time` package and its subpackages.

Comment: Or "yoda time", as pretty much everything is better than using Calendar and Date^^

Comment: Just a hint: you can call `max` on a stream instead of collecting into a `List` and passing that `List` to `Collections.max`. And if you provide a `Comparator` comparing the dates, you can get the file in the first place.

Comment: @Holger Could you pleas elaborate on that? I don't seem to understand about the comparator part.

Comment: No need to use `Date` or `java.time`; just use a `Comparator` that works directly on the filename.

Comment: Yes, the comparator you implement should do the string disassembly and date-time parsing. And as others said, avoid the wretched mess that is `Date`/`Calendar`; use only java.time classes, specifically `LocalDate` in your case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the dates always have the specified six-character representation, you may use

```
Optional<FTPFile> max = ftpFiles.stream()
    .filter(file -> file.getName().startsWith(prefix))
    .max(Comparator.comparing(file -> file.getName()
           .replaceFirst(".*_([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{4}).*", "$3$2$1")));
```

The factory method `Comparator.comparing` allows you to create a `Comparator` based on a property, so that the maximum element will be the element with the maximum value for that property.

Note that this simply converts the `ddmmyyyy` formatted date to a `yyyymmdd` string which can be compared lexicographically, which works as long as the day and months always have a two-digit form, i.e. with a leading zero.

You may optimize this a bit by preparing and reusing the regex pattern:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*_([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{4}).*");
Optional<FTPFile> max = ftpFiles.stream()
        .filter(file -> file.getName().startsWith(prefix))
        .max(Comparator.comparing(file ->
                pattern.matcher(file.getName()).replaceFirst("$3$2$1")));
```

---

If the `DateFormat` is an unavoidable prerequisite, you may use

```
Optional<FTPFile> max = ftpFiles.stream()
        .filter(file -> file.getName().startsWith(prefix))
        .max(Comparator.comparing(file -> {
                String name = file.getName();
                name = name.substring(name.indexOf('_')+1);
                try {
                    return dateFormat.parse(name);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
                }
            }));
```

This performs the operation in one go, but has the disadvantage of performing the parsing operation more than necessary during the comparisons. If you want to avoid that, you may resort to the original two pass design, but you still don’t need to collect into a `List`:

```
ftpFiles.stream()
        .map(FTPFile::getName)
        .filter(name -> name.startsWith(prefix))
        .map(name -> {
                name = name.substring(name.indexOf('_')+1);
                try {
                    return dateFormat.parse(name);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
                }
            })
        .max(Comparator.naturalOrder())
        .map(date -> prefix+'_'+dateFormat.format(date))
        .flatMap(fileName -> ftpFiles.stream()
                               .filter(file -> file.getName().equals(fileName)).findAny())
        .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Comment: This seems really interesting, but the name of the file can change, i mean, it could be mmddyy or ddmmyy or whatever, so thats why I tried to convert it to date first.

Comment: @Marci-man: no parser can magically detect whether you mean `mmddyy` or `ddmmyy`, so you would have to re-configure the parser in any case. In case of my answer, using `mmddyyyy` instead of `ddmmyyyy` is as simple as changing `"$3$2$1"` to `"$3$1$2"`. Of course, that’s only maintainable once you understood what it does. Adapting it to support `yy` additionally to `yyyy` would be a bit harder, but I strongly discourage using two digit years anyway. But well, you can use `Comparator.comparing` to create a `Date` parser based comparator as well, it would be just a little less efficient then.

Comment: No, this not what I meant, I get a format beforehand: mainimport_ddmmyy. This piece of information is already there.